# Looping in Python 3

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-3.x

This is my program. Any ideas on how I can make the whole thing loop, but only if the input is incorrect? I've already set a large integer for the range, but I can't figure out where and how to set the conditions to make it happen. Everything I've tried so far has given me an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def main():

  for i in range(1000):

    date = (input("enter the date as dd/mm/yyyy: "))

    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d/%m/%Y")
        print ("Format is Correct")
    except:
        ValueError
        print ("Format is Incorrect")

    date = day, month, year = date.split("/")
    if len(day) == 1 or len(day) == 2:
        day = int(day)
        if len(month) == 1 or len(month) == 2:
            month = int(month)
            months = ["emp", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
                      "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
            if len(year) == 4:
                year = int(year)
                if 1899 < year < 3001:
                    if year % 100 == 0:
                        if year % 400 == 0:
                            print ("It's a leap year")
                        else:
                            print ("It is not a lea[ year")
                    else:
                        if year % 4 == 0:
                            print ("It's a leap year")
                        else:
                            print ("It is not a leapyear")
                else:
                    print ("The year is not in range")
                if month > 12 or month < 0:
                    print ("The month is out of range")
                elif month == 4 or month == 6 or  month == 9 or month == 11:
                    if day > 30:
                        print ("The date is out of range for the month")
                elif month == 2:
                    if day > 29:
                        print ("The date is out of range for the month")
                print(day, months[month], year)            

main()
```

Comment: Don't use for with a large integer for your loop. You can use `while(condition)` to do your stuff and with setting good condition you don't even need to use `continue` keyword in your loop but It's bad idea to use for in your program.

Comment: @HamidFzM Could you give an example of how to use a while loop in this specific situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `continue` to go back to the beginning of the loop:

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d/%m/%Y")
    print ("Format is Correct")
except ValueError:
    print ("Format is Incorrect")
    continue
```

Comment: Placing the continue there is causing the program to continue to loop even if the input is corect

Comment: @Manaar That can't be true.  Is your indentation correct?

Comment: @sashkello I recommend `except ValueError:` since it appears that was the intent of the OP in the original code.